# MacPorts / Terminal: `Unrecognized action "sudo"`

Tags: macos, terminal, imagemagick, macports, mamp

I'm trying to install Image Magick on MAMP. And I'm seriously out of my depth.

I've installed MacPorts, and opened the terminal. I've typed in `sudo port -v selfupdate` per the instructions on http://www.macports.org/install.php#pkg

But the response I get from the Terminal is `Unrecognized action "sudo"`

I've googled and googled, but can't find anything that makes a slab of sense.

Any clever people feeling generous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running ports on interactive mode, and you are not in your system shell. The port program won't recognize sudo as one of its commands, and I am guessing you didn't run your port command with sudo so you won't be able to do much, try the following:

- Click on your terminal.
- Press command + Q (command is the key left of your space bar)
- Open your terminal once again and do not run anything on else but the command suggested:

  sudo port -v selfupdate

If you get the same thing, you are still or again in Macports interactive session, type CTRL + C, or type quit.

Comment: I have the same issue. Doesn't work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MacOS Ventura then there exists an issue with this command

Once you installed the dmg file installer:

Add in below commands self-update is not required:

Type in **sudo port** this will give you the version and will allow you to enter via a shell mode

Following that you can type in **version** or **help** to get more details on actions to follow[image]