# sudo: port: command not found

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, macports, xcode4.3, bash

I recently uninstalled Xcode 4.2 and re-installed Xcode 4.3.1. Command Line Tools are installed. I then installed MacPort using “dmg” disk images for Lion from macports.org. Since, I was getting `sudo: port: command not found` after every use of port, I followed [this](http://bparanj.blogspot.com/2007/03/sudo-port-command-not-found.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) to create a `.bash_profile` file(wasn't present earlier) and then put in it the following but to no avail.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info
```

Following [this post](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/macports/)

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local
You requested building with '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ vi .rvmrc 

rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"

export CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"

export CFLAGS="-O2 -arch x86_64"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"
```

Renaming `.bash_profile` to `.profile`

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ vi .bash_profile
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ mv .bash_profile .profile
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ mv .profile              
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ mv -f .bash_profile .profile
mv: rename .bash_profile to .profile: No such file or directory
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ port
zsh: correct 'port' to 'pr' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: port
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which port
port not found
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗
```

`.profile` content:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info
```

Comment: I ran into this error in the command line when installing MongoDB for a Rails app, so I imagine some others may also find this question via Google search with the same keywords. All I did was update XCode and install MacPorts from macports.org, try that before doing anything else on this page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure to delete ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash_login so that .profile can work. This worked for me http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/fixing-bash-profile-in-os-x/

Comment: I restarted my terminal and it's gone again :-/

Comment: what's gone, your .profile? BTW can you still use sudo in the terminal? like sudo ls for example?

Comment: port. I have to run `source .profile` every time when I open terminal for it to recognize port.

Comment: sounds like you still have .bash_profile or .bash_login http://superuser.com/questions/366642/profile-not-loaded-osx-lion

Comment: The link to the solution is not available anymore.

Comment: Link to the solution is not available any more. This is why the solution should be posted here and not just the link.

Comment: Why would you want to delete your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_*` for that matter, ever? Especially if you spent a lot of time configuring your bash, all of that configuration will be gone instantly and many tools that you use daily will be gone.

Comment: This is far to be a solution, first of all, you'll gonna delete all your personal profile bash data, and this is not mean it'll gonna work because the problem is related to paths of the system, the correct solution is provided by @Isis.

Comment: johnnywey.wordpress.com is no longer available.

Answer (score 148):

First, you might need to edit your system's PATH

```
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Add 2 following lines:

```
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
```

**Reboot your terminal**

Comment: After lots of .bash_profile investigation, it turned out I just needed to reboot the terminal after installing MacPorts. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: It works for me too! Thank you. This should be the right answer.

Comment: @Ila just rebooting terminal worked for me. Thank you for help :)

Comment: Kindly help me:Bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287906/error-while-installing-firebase-via-cocoapods

Comment: Adding those two lines and rebooting the terminal was what finally did the trick after messing around with .bash_profile and .profile. All of it fruitless until I added opt/local/bin to etc/paths.

Comment: You can also add this line to `/etc/manpaths`: `/opt/local/share/man`

Comment: For the record, this worked to solve the same problem on High Sierra as well.

Comment: This is the real solution, @Ava please tag the correct answer.

Comment: It might be a good solution for some cases, but if you do not have sudo access and installed mactools as such, I am afraid another solution would be necessary.

Answer (score 21):

I found the answer in [the official website](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.shell.html)

```
$ vi ~/.profile

# add the following line
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

And now restart the terminal or type `source !$` (equivalent to `source ~/.profile`)

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that finally helped me. I actually didn't have a `.profile`, so I created one and added that line and it worked.

Answer (score 18):

You could try to source your profile file to update your environment:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

Comment: How do I do source my profile? How do I run this command, just writing it on terminal gives `source: no such file or directory: .profile`

Comment: move into your user directory with `cd $HOME` then try it

Comment: Yes, I am trying from there only.

Comment: OP has a `.bash_profile`, not a `.profile`. Rename that file to `~/.profile` and try again.

Comment: I renamed it to `.profile`. Is it different from `~/.profile`?

Comment: It's the same `~/` is just the path to the user directory (same as `$HOME/` )

Comment: Kindly help me:Bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287906/error-while-installing-firebase-via-cocoapods

Answer (score 18):

if you use zsh.please add flowing string to the line 'export PATH="..."' in file '~/.zshrc'

```
:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

Comment: You can also set `MANPATH` with `export MANPATH="/opt/local/share/man"`. If you want to be able to access MacPorts in non-login shells, set these variables in `~/.zshenv`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was editing .profile, .bash_profile till now. Finally edited .zshrc and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

On my machine, port is in `/opt/local/bin/port` - try typing that into a terminal on its own.

Comment: In my bin folder, there are only files(port is a file) `➜  bin  ls
daemondo   port       portf      portindex  portmirror`

Comment: What do you get when you type `set | grep PATH' into a terminal?

Comment: Binary file (standard input) matches

Comment: Sorry, don't know where to go from there. This might help: http://willbryant.net/software/mac_os_x/paths

Comment: I do not have a `path.d` inside etc folder. I only have macports inside it.

Comment: there is no /opt folder on my mac Osx 10.8?

Answer (score 6):

If you have just installed macports
just run and it should work

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you get from running `which port` as your regular user account? Try it from a freshly opened terminal. Try again after renaming `.bash_profile` to `.profile`. Can you run `port` as a regular user, even with no arguments?

Comment: Added it above. It is renamed.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite simply add the line:

```
source ~/.profile
```

To the bottom of your shell rc file - if you are using bash then it would be your ~/.bash_profile if you are using zsh it would be your ~/.zshrc

Then open a new Terminal window and type ports -v you should see output that looks like the following:

```
~ [ port -v                                                                                                              ] 12:12 pm
MacPorts 2.1.3
Entering interactive mode... ("help" for help, "quit" to quit)
[Users/sh] > quit
Goodbye
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

there might be the situation your machine is managed by Puppet or so. Then changing root .profile or .bash_rc file does not work at all.
Therefore you could add the following to your .profile file. After that you can use "mydo" instead of "sudo". It works perfectly for me.

```
function mydo() {
    echo Executing sudo with: "$1" "${@:2}"
    sudo $(which $1) "${@:2}"
}
```

Visit my page: http://www.danielkoitzsch.de/blog/2016/03/16/sudo-returns-xyz-command-not-found/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this as an issue with port trees. MacPorts offers a solution [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/PortTreeTarball), which worked for me and does not imply changing your environment variables.