# MacPorts- port: command not found?

Tags: python, macports, macos-mojave, fluidsynth

I am a beginning programmer playing around with making fractal music in python. I am thinking of using the mingus module to play the notes, however mingus need to have fluidsynth installed. I am trying to install fluidsynth using MacPorts. I have the fluidsynth files. When i run

```
sudo port install fluidsynth
```

on my Mac terminal it asks for my password, which i enter. It then says

> sudo: port: command not found"

What is going wrong? I am on a macOs mojave, if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that you may have not installed `MacPorts` correctly. Follow the `MacPorts` documentation to install it correctly. Once installed, you can run a command like

```
port installed
```

to list all of your ports.

If that worked then you can do this

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and it should work.
See more possible solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found)

Comment: Thanks! I have now installed MacPorts correctly and then successfully installed fluidsynth version 2.0.5 but when using fluidsynth in mingus it still says ImportError: Couldn't find the FluidSynth library." Shouldn't this work since i have fluidsynth installed now?

Answer (score 2):

as @Ila says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found#:%7E:text=After%20lots%20of%20.bash_profile%20investigation%2C%20it%20turned%20out%20I%20just%20needed%20to%20reboot%20the%20terminal%20after%20installing%20MacPorts.%20Thanks%20for%20this%20tip):

> After lots of .bash_profile investigation, it turned out I just needed
> to **reboot the terminal** after installing MacPorts.